# Is it possible to overload Typescript functions for optional parameters in this way?

Tags: typescript, overloading, destructuring

I think the answer to this is probably that there is not a way to do this as I haven't figured out how to make it work but here is what I would like to do. Let's say I have a function that takes in 3 numbers with the last two being optional. I would like to allow the optional parameters to be provided as either their own parameters or combined into an object where each parameter is optional.

Something like this is as close as I could get but destructuring doesn't work:

```
function add(a: number, b?: number, c?: number): number;
function add(a: number, {b, c}: {b?: number, c?: number}): number;
function add(a: number, b?: any, c?: number): number {
    return a + (b ? b : 0) + (c ? c : 0);
}
console.log('a + b + c: ' + add(3, undefined, 8));
console.log('a + b + c: ' + add(3, {c: 8}));
```

```
a + b + c: 11
a + b + c: 3[object Object]0
```

The actual use case is a method with a lot more parameters that we want to keeps backwards compatible but would like to add the object variety for simplicity when calling it.

Answer (score 0):

Overload call signatures and type annotations are part of TypeScript's static type system, which is [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) when TypeScript code is transpiled to JavaScript.

That means that your `add()` function becomes the following when it's actually run:

```
// transpiled
function add(a, b, c) {
    return a + (b ? b : 0) + (c ? c : 0);
}
```

As you can see, there's no destructuring going on there.  If you want `b` and `c` to come from either the argument pair or a single object, you will need that logic to happen inside the function *implementation*.  Here's how I might write that:

```
function add(a: number, b?: number, c?: number): number;
function add(a: number, { b, c }: { b?: number, c?: number }): number;
function add(a: number, p1?: number | { b?: number, c?: number }, p2?: number): number {
    const b = typeof p1 === "object" ? p1.b : p1;
    const c = typeof p1 === "object" ? p1.c : p2
    return a + (b || 0) + (c || 0);
}
```

The implementation signature has arguments named `p1` and `p2` which are unions of the analogous arguments from possible ways of calling `add()`.  Then we have to compute `b` and `c` from `p1` and `p2`.  This should work the way you expect:

```
console.log('a + b + c: ' + add(3, undefined, 8)); // 11
console.log('a + b + c: ' + add(3, { c: 8 })); // 11
```

Okay, I hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoBTIFyLCAWwCMBTAJwBpEiB+XfY8qiOvQ0sgSnvfIG4AsAChQkWAhTosPRpUQBvas0QBfXItoyOzVgw6rubWYJHho8JGkw4j2xAAcAjLt5lEAHwXUXsnVvKqVPYATD4chnoB8sKIsYgQCADOUNSIALyIUACe9iRwwA6O6WkZAERwRABWJNCliDSFAHREiLhOJnHxSSkQ6Zk5eQVOxWUV1bX1Tb1twTFxZCRQIGSWiADUiBgt7p4ADJzrm707iPsmKsIJYIlwADYkjbdwAOYYAOTIhy0bELhvh1YMABmKjgVAkYAwMAkVBUAAcnE4fEQAHoUYhHI5Lkk7g8nq8Pl9Dr9EP8NoCQV4SXCDEjUejMcIgA)

Comment: Ya, that's pretty much what I figured. Unfortunately, for the use case we have we can't guarantee that the first optional parameter is not an object. I assume under that scenario there isn't a good way to handle this?